# How to I style the Superfish accordion menu to have bars?

Tags: routes, navigation

I would like to show my super fish menu with bars as shown in the picture (when in mobile responsive mode), but at the moment i can only get the word "Menu". The menu functions perfectly, i just wanted to add the bars. Can anyone advise?[image]

Comment: you can accomplish this using CSS. With your browser right click on the MENU and inspect element. Find the div **class** or **id** that MENU uses and [add a background image using css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing you are using responsive and that implies that you are size aware. You may find an icon set more elegant rather than a fixed sized background image.

I load the [font-awesome set](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) into the site css anyway for use elsewhere. Therefor the icon's css are available sitewide.

If you look at the accordian settings for that sf menu, you'll see that you can edit that menu button (trigger) text. I found that though a text field, it does accept some html.

For example
`Open Menu<i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

gives you those [the bars](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/bars/) and they re-size as the button text does.